# How to invoke Google Maps Navigation without three 'backs' being required?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-gps

I've written an app which invokes Google Maps/Navigation:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + lat + "," + lng)
);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This works perfectly, except (on Android 5 and 6) the user has to press back three times to get back to my app.

The first "back" takes them out of live navigation, back to a screen showing the route.

The second "back" takes them out of navigation, back to a map screen showing their current location.

The third "back" takes them back to my app.

How can I make one "back" take them out of Google Maps/Navigation entirely, back to my app?